# I'm unable to set the viewBinding in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin, build.gradle, android-viewbinding, viewbinding

I'm stucked like 5 days in this problem!
I'm unable to bind the view using viewBinding clause in Android Studio, I believe the problem is in "build.gradle" file.

Initially, I tried to build the project in the way that I knew:

```
buildFeatures { viewBinding true }
```

But it didn't work... I went to the Android Official page to see, and apparently they changed the syntax to:

```
viewBinding { enabled = true }
```

Even so, it shows an error: the word "enabled" is subbed and do not let the gradle build the program.

I have also tried:

```
viewBinding { enable = true }
viewBinding { enable }
viewBinding { enable true }
 
buildFeatures { viewBinding { enabled = true } }
buildFeatures { viewBinding.isEnabled } 
 
// Among numerous other possibilities...
```

I also tried to define the viewBinding globally, in gradle.properties:

```
android.viewBinding.enabled=true
```

Did not work.

I looked at the imports as well:

```
import com.example.mvvmstudy.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
// The mistake does not seems to be here
```

As well, I tried to verify the gradle version, but it seems to be up to date, I'm using version **8.3** with the **8.1.1** plugin.

What may be the problem??
I have already rebuild the project many many times, I did 2 other new projects and the issue still there hahahahaha

The project is just an exemplo about how MVVM works, I defined a button just to set a Toast and see the binding works, but I'm not been able to do it...

Repository: https://github.com/DaniloVolles/MVVMStudy

I did already seen:
1 - [When I add viewBinding in gradle in Android Studio, it comes an error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62951769/when-i-add-viewbinding-in-gradle-in-android-studio-it-comes-an-error)

2 - [What's the difference between viewBinding enabled true and buildfeatures viewBinding true](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71972954/whats-the-difference-between-viewbinding-enabled-true-and-buildfeatures-viewbin)

3 - [cannot access viewBinding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65031149/cannot-access-viewbinding)

And some others, but neither worked...

Comment: https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#setup

Answer (score 3):

In `Gradle Kotlin DSL (KTS)`, the syntax is different from Groovy. Here is the correct way to enable View Binding in an Android project using Gradle Kotlin DSL:

```
buildFeatures {
        viewBinding = true
}
```

Instead of

```
buildFeatures {
        viewBinding true
}
```

In Gradle Kotlin DSL, assignments are done using the `=` operator.

For More Info You will find here : https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/view-binding#setup

and for Gradle Kotlin DSL (KTS) : https://developer.android.com/build/migrate-to-kotlin-dsl#prefix-boolean